# Accessing private member values with external template function

Tags: class, templates, friend

I'm a noob of c++, I'm trying to use a template function to get the private members inside a class because there are two types of parameters.
What I wrote is like:

```
template <typename Type>
Type const& Get(Type const& value)
{
  return value;
}

class Event{
public:
Event(int const InputYear, int const InputMonth, int const InputDay, char const* InputContent, char const* InputNa    me = "None")
       :Year(InputYear), Month(InputMonth), Day(InputDay), Content(InputContent), Name(InputName)
  {
      
  }
   
  ~Event();
 
private:
  int Year;
  int Month;
  int Day;
  char* Content;
  char* Name;
 
  friend Type const& Get(Type const& value);
};
```

I don't know if my definition of `friend` is correct, if not could someone tell me how to use such template to access the private members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification tells us that under certain circumstances (in this case explicit template instantiations), the usual access checking rules are not applied.

> 12 The usual access checking rules do not apply to names used to specify explicit instantiations. [ Note: In
> particular, the template arguments and names used in the function declarator (including parameter types,
> return types and exception specifications) may be private types or objects which would normally not be
> accessible and the template may be a member template or member function which would not normally be
> accessible. — end note ]

Thus, we can use this property to make a generic getter to a private member.

```cpp
template <auto Event::* Member>
struct Getter {
    friend auto &get(Event &e) { return e.*Member; }
};

template struct Getter<&Event::Year>;
auto &get(Event &e);

Event event{2021, 12, 24, "some event description"};
int year = get(event); // 2021
```

Comment: Hmmm...Sorry I can not understand why you defined two template then it can access the private members of the class?

Comment: @Crisps I defined only one template structure which takes a single non-type template parameter pointer to a member of Event. Inside this structure, I create a friend declaration which returns the private member. Then, I make an explicit template instantiation by specifying the private member I want to access. Friend functions which are defined at their friend declarations do not introduce names which are visible with ordinary lookup into the enclosing namespace although they have namespace scope, meaning that a matching declaration needs to be provided at namespace scope in order to be found.